# WINDOWS 10 stuck at automatic repair after dual booting with UBUNTU 18.04

Tags: windows, windows-10, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

Every time I try booting my windows 10 it always shows the "Preparing Automatic Repair" then the "Diagnosing Your PC" then the "Attempting Repair" but after that it shows "Automatic Repair couldn't repair your PC". However, my ubuntu OS works fine. I researched and found a possible solution which is to turn off the FastStartUp mode of windows. So I tried it by entering this command `REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power" /V HiberbootEnabled /T REG_dWORD /D 0 /F` on an elavated cmd (I saw it here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2324331&p=13488472#post13488472) then rebooted my pc. But it didn't fixed it. Any helped would be very much appreciated.

UEFI is used for both OS. GPT also used for both OS.

Comment: Yes, it's recommended to turn off FastStartUp but that should be done *before* having a problem. You can try to repair Windows using a Windows installation USB stick, that off that new feature and then it should be fine. Avoid mounting the Windows system partition in Ubuntu and it won't mess up your Windows partition.

Comment: I see. Will this delete or affect my ubuntu OS in any ways?

Comment: It shouldn't if both are installed in UEFI mode. In BIOS it will likely replace Grub with the Windows bootloader but *shouldn't* mess with other partitions. It never happened to me but some people say it may delete the Ubuntu partition or corrupt it.

Comment: Information needed, BIOS or UEFI, MBR or GPT, How did you install your bootloader. Did you stupidly mount NTFS in Linux after a hybrid sleep of Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix my problem by following method 2 in this tutorial https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/restore-repair-deleted-efi-boot-partition-in-windows-10-8-7.html
It seems that I stupidly deleted my efi boot partition.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

My setup:
Dual boot Win10, ubuntu22, grub2 EFI.

Problem: Every time I used to boot into Win10 the boot process failed a couple of times, then Windows automatic repair, followed by a successful boot into Win10.

Solution:
Step 1 - Disable fast startup in windows.
Step 2 - Disable automatic mount. Run CMD as admin. In CMD: "diskpart", "automount disable".
Step 3 - Reboot. Problem should be gone.